# sage writing and reading from files; spesific example

Tags: functional-programming, algebra, sage

As I am new in programming with SAGE, I wonder whether anyone can help me in this topic which I think is a matter of writing results to a file first, and then taking them from there.

In particular,
I have a command like this;

```html
n = 11
K = GF(4,'a')
R = PolynomialRing(GF(4,'a'),"x")
x = R.gen()
a = K.gen()

v = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
R(v)
f = x^n-R(v)
S = R.quotient(f, 'y')
y = S.gen()
```

In the later steps I am using this v as a list of coefficients of a polynomial. And I do some algebra on them. But I want this v to run over all possible 11-length vectors over the finite field K as I defined. And I want to get the results for each v separately.

How can I write a program that will do this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
n = 11
K = GF(4,'a')
for v in VectorSpace(K, n):
    do stuff with v
```

On my computer, it took 14.1 seconds to construct the list of all vectors in `VectorSpace(K, 10)`, 55 seconds for `VectorSpace(K, 11)`. When you run the loop, it doesn't construct the list all at once, so there is no long pause at the beginning and it shouldn't fill up a lot of memory, it iterates through the elements of the vector space pretty quickly.

If you really want to write to a file, you should investigate file input and output in Python, for example [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).